# Measure engagement on a per product basis

Tags: personalization, engagement-plans, goals

I'm trying to measure engagement *per product* and I'm spinning my wheels a bit. Goals seems to be close to what I'm going for but "engagement value" is a one-dimensional metric when what I really need is something more like the ability to measure engagement with product_1 and compare that to engagement with product_2. Any ideas on where to look to set up a structure like that?

I intend on comparing these values to decide which product should be promoted on the front page of the website when the user returns in order to help them pick up where they left off with greater ease.

Comment: Each product is a page. I think you can just trigger events/goal/outcomes for the engagements you want to score. And then compare them in path analyzer.

Comment: @ChrisAuer that would be fine if I only wanted to measure engagement based on page views but I also want to increase the value when a button is clicked, a picture is viewed or more information is requested.

Comment: Gotcha. For the button click, you can use the SBOS link tracker to fire an event and increase EV when the link is clicked. https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/SitecoreSBOSLinkTracker.aspx If the viewing of the image and request more info is client side, you can call an API to increase the EV. I use APIs for events, goals and EV all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both for your answers. I did a bit more digging and came across this blog post:

http://ie.com.au/sitecore-personalisation-based-on-highest-ranking-profile-key

This achieves exactly what I need to do using Personas and Profiles. It seemed like the neatest and most concise way to achieve my goal so I followed his method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the goals on the products. Once the user triggers the goal on the product, this is recorded into MongoDB at the user session end.

Sitecore stores those data into the *PageEvents* which are then flushed into the Analytics Database.

From the Analytics / Reporting Database, there is a table call `Fact_Conversions`. All goals that have been triggered are stored into that table.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, you can have the relevant data which can help you to know which item has performed better.

Using Entity Framework, you can query the `Fact_Conversions` table and filters those data to get the products which is best performing.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use patterns on the content. If each product page triggers you toward one pattern or another, then you could run your personalization on the home page based on the user's identified persona.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/insession_personalization/pattern_cards